# Problem downloading large app using iPad 2

Tags: ipad, error

I tried to download a 500MB app using my iPad 2 connected to WiFi and got an error stating that the app could not be downloaded.

Someone told me that its because the file is too large to be downloaded from the iPad and that I will have to download the app via iTunes on a PC and then sync it with my iPad.

How true is this? And how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you tell us what the exact error "text" was? As far as I know, I don't think there's a limit for wifi download (only on 3G, and I think it depends on your operator)

Comment: The 3G download limit is imposed by iOS and currently stands at 20MB over 3G.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when this happens it's usually down to the fact that the download process failed (for whatever reason) and iOS will not allow you to recommence the download or try starting it again from scratch. It's not so much to do with a software imposed download limitation.

There's only a limit over 3G (20MB) and a general limit on app sizes (2GB).

The only thing I can suggest is trying to delete the app from the home screen and restarting the download (although I'm doubtful this will work).

**Otherwise, you will have to connect to iTunes and install as it suggests. For large apps, I tend to do this due to problems like you have experienced and because it's usually quicker!**

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your iPad will not exceed its capacity during the download, otherwise it will stop the download.